# Plotly: unable to communicate with the local orca server process, even though the server process seems to be running

Tags: python, plotly

When I render a plotly figure to a file as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def produce_graph(graph, data_dir):
    figure = go.Figure()
    [...]
    figure.write_image("output_file.png")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1559, in to_image
    figure=fig_dict, format=format, scale=scale, width=width, height=height
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 696, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1474, in request_image_with_retrying
    raise OSError("522: client socket timeout")
OSError: 522: client socket timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "study/make_graphs.py", line 169, in <module>
    main()
  File "study/make_graphs.py", line 166, in main
    produce_graph(graph, args.data_dir)
  File "study/make_graphs.py", line 70, in produce_graph
    figure.write_image(output_file_name)
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 2824, in write_image
    return pio.write_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1767, in write_image
    fig, format=format, scale=scale, width=width, height=height, validate=validate
  File "/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1591, in to_image
    info=status_str
ValueError: 
For some reason plotly.py was unable to communicate with the
local orca server process, even though the server process seems to be running.

Please review the process and connection information below:

orca status
-----------
    state: running
    executable: /usr/local/bin/orca
    version: 1.2.1
    port: 65465
    pid: 90478
    command: ['/usr/local/bin/orca', 'serve', '-p', '65465', '--plotly', '/Users/brunorijsman/cascade-python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/package_data/plotly.min.js', '--graph-only', '--mathjax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js']
```

I also tried rendering to a .png file and to a .jpeg file and I get the exact same error in those cases as well.

Rendering the figure to a browser works fine:

```
figure.show()
```

I already tried adding the following, but it made no difference:

```
plotly.io.orca.ensure_server()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

as [this issue](https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/240#issuecomment-629881470)

you should set timeout disabled

```py
# Disable the orca response timeout.
import plotly.io._orca
import retrying
unwrapped = plotly.io._orca.request_image_with_retrying.__wrapped__
wrapped = retrying.retry(wait_random_min=1000)(unwrapped)
plotly.io._orca.request_image_with_retrying = wrapped
```